# UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Springboot Test

Tags: autowired, spring-boot-test

What must I do to fix, that a testing class isn't able to resolve a autowired dependency, though the Springboot app is autoconfiguring as the test is? I did not intantiate an own object, of course. Is there a simple way to do so?

The class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PostClient.class, NumberplateClientCommands.class})
public class NumberplateClientCommandsTest {

    private StandardMethodTargetRegistrar registrar = new StandardMethodTargetRegistrar();
    private ConfigurableCommandRegistry registry = new ConfigurableCommandRegistry();
    private Map<String, MethodTarget> commands;

    @Autowired
    public PostClient postClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(NumberplateClientCommands.class);
        registrar.setApplicationContext(context);
        registrar.register(registry);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddTwoIntegers() {
        commands = registry.listCommands();

        MethodTarget methodTarget = commands.get("sum");

        assertThat(methodTarget, notNullValue());
        Assertions.assertThat(methodTarget.getGroup()).isEqualTo(
                "Numberplate Client Commands");
        assertThat(methodTarget.getHelp(), Is.is("Add up to sum."));
        assertThat(methodTarget.getMethod(), is(
                ReflectionUtils.findMethod(NumberplateClientCommands.class, "sum", int.class,
                        int.class)));
        assertThat(methodTarget.getAvailability().isAvailable(), is(true));
        assertEquals(3, ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(methodTarget.getMethod(),
                methodTarget.getBean(), 1, 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSayHi() {
        commands = registry.listCommands();
        MethodTarget methodTarget = commands.get("say-hi");

        assertThat(methodTarget, notNullValue());
        Assertions.assertThat(methodTarget.getGroup()).isEqualTo(
                "Numberplate Client Commands");
        assertThat(methodTarget.getHelp(), Is.is("Saying hi to a given person's name."));
        assertThat(methodTarget.getMethod(), is(
                ReflectionUtils.findMethod(NumberplateClientCommands.class, "sayHi", String.class)));
        assertThat(methodTarget.getAvailability().isAvailable(), is(true));
        assertEquals("Hi, Nadine", ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(methodTarget.getMethod(),
                methodTarget.getBean(), "Nadine"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldPostCamImage2kafka() throws FileNotFoundException {
        commands = registry.listCommands();
        MethodTarget methodTarget = commands.get("one");
        NumberPlateUtility np = new NumberPlateUtility();
        HttpStatus response = postClient.postNumberPlate(np.completeImage());
        assertThat(response, is(HttpStatus.OK));
    }
}
```

The Exception is:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'numberplateClientCommands': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'postClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.semo.npgen.service.PostClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I shared [my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Semo/npgen), if that may help. Other questions and answers show very specific solutions, which often depend on some @Repository or other MVC-like components, interfaces or complex controllers, which I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you make another application context in the setUp(before) method of your test and select only one configuration file (NumberplateClientCommands) there.

I can suggest you to try something like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PostClient.class, NumberplateClientCommands.class})
public class NumberplateClientCommandsTest {

    ...

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        registrar.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        registrar.register(registry);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddTwoIntegers() {
    ...
    }
```